# ansible : playbook still fails even if ignore_errors is set to "yes"

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I got the following task in an ansible playbook...

```
- name: Check if default ssh user exist  
  shell: whoami  
  remote_user: "{{default_ssh_user_info.name}}"  
  ignore_errors: yes  
  register: results
```

The objective is to check if the user `{{default_ssh_user_info.name}}` is configured on the remote machine, in case it is not, I would connect as a root user and create it with the following tasks.

However, it looks that `ignore_errors` does not catch the error... and this my ansible playbook stop. Is there a way to catch this kind of error ? Is it a bug ?

Here are the error messages:

```
fatal: [local.datadevserver.aplazame.com] => SSH encountered an unknown error. The output was:
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/updiversity/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/updiversity/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket "/home/updiversity/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-192.168.33.10-22-cox" does not exist
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.33.10 [192.168.33.10] port 22.
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: timeout: 10000 ms remain after connect
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/updiversity/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/updiversity/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/updiversity/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/updiversity/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/updiversity/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/updiversity/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/updiversity/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/updiversity/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/updiversity/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.33.10" from file "/home/updiversity/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/updiversity/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com zlib@openssh.com
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com zlib@openssh.com
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 

    a7:6c:80:f6:a8:00:ba:df:5e:2a:57:f5:49:f1:63:da
    debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.33.10" from file "/home/updiversity/.ssh/known_hosts"
    debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/updiversity/.ssh/known_hosts:3
    debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
    debug1: Host '192.168.33.10' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /home/updiversity/.ssh/known_hosts:3
    debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
    debug2: kex_derive_keys
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
    debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug2: key: /home/updiversity/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f23bb7b3ca0),
    debug2: key: updiversity@PC-Lenovo (0x7f23bb7b94f0),
    debug2: key: /home/updiversity/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
    debug2: key: /home/updiversity/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
    debug2: key: /home/updiversity/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
    debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
    debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
    debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
    debug3: remaining preferred: ,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
    debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/updiversity/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug3: send_pubkey_test
    debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
    debug1: Offering RSA public key: updiversity@PC-Lenovo
    debug3: send_pubkey_test
    debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/updiversity/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug3: no such identity: /home/updiversity/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/updiversity/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug3: no such identity: /home/updiversity/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/updiversity/.ssh/id_ed25519
    debug3: no such identity: /home/updiversity/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
    debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
    debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
    Permission denied (publickey,password).



FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

**FOLLOW-UP**

I am trying the following solution:

```
  - name: Check if default ssh user exist
    shell: id -u {{ default_ssh_user_info.name }}
    remote_user: "{{ init_ssh_user_info.name }}"
    ignore_errors: yes
    register: results
    sudo: yes
    when: init_ssh_user_info.name is defined
```

The only problem I have it is that the SSH connection still fails as it does not find the private key. Is it possible to specify the path of the private key for a specific task in Ansible ? I could not find it in the documentation.

Comment: Please include the error(s) and command execution results.

Answer (score 1):

The thing here is, Ansible does not fail directly on your task, but already while connecting to the host. That is a fatal error and you can not `ignore_errors` on this level.

You have three options I see,

- Run the task as root (not necessarily, if you have another user that you know exists for sure, you can use that) and check if the user exists:

  ```
  - shell: id -u {{ default_ssh_user_info.name }}
    register: results
    sudo: yes
  ```
- Create your own ssh connection through a shell task:

  ```
  - shell: ssh {{ default_ssh_user_info.name }}@{{ inventory_hostname }} whoami
    delegate: localhost
    register: results
  ```

But I wonder why you need such a check in the first place. When you use the [user module](http://docs.ansible.com/user_module.html) Ansible would only create the user if it does not exist (erm... how could it not ;-)). If you want to trigger own actions depending on if the user was just created, you can `register` that output and check for the `changed` property.

```
- user: name={{ default_ssh_user_info.name }}
  sudo: yes
  register: user_created

- debug: msg="User was created"
  when: user_created | changed
```